# SMS from Anchor link - Html5 Iphone

Tags: ios, html, cordova

Is it possible to trigger a SMS via a hyperlink in a HTML5 Iphone app - in the same way that mailto: and tel: works?

i.e.?

```
  <a href="mailto:joeblogs@blah.net">mail</a>
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `sms:`? It is an official RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5724

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
sms:12345678?body=TEXT
```

where `12345678` is the phone number